# How to get total amount with discounts (all rules applied) before Order Review?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, payment-methods

I have cart rules applied by payment methods.

And my custom Credit Card payment send authorization request in step five (before Order Review).

But Cart Rules are applied at Order Review only (step 6).

I'm trying like below but `$amount` is wrong (with no discounts).

```
public function authorize(Varien_Object $payment, $amount)
```

How to get price discounts in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Not in front of pc, so no examples.

Sound like you need to issue a collecttotals() on the cart object before you authorize.

Don't have a handle on your custom code, but essentially, where the passed $amount value is calculated, ensure you do a call to ->collecttotals() on the cart object.

This will allow your cart totals to be calculated, taking all the various discounting and tax calculations into consideration.

If all goes well, the value of $amount will then be correct.

Untested.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. But my question is more about Payment based Cart Rule's. There is no discount until a payment method is selected. And another big issue... when submited to Order Review. If customer returns to address or shipping step (or where else page) pay methods that displays price/installments are with wrong rules.